# django in one queryset all and filter methods

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I trying display in django app, in view last 5 item and also this items which has is_home set on True.

Please hint if this is 'nice' and correct way:

My model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()
    is_home = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My query in view:

```
context['event_list'] = Event.objects.filter(Q(Event.objects.all()) | Event.objects.filter(is_home=True))[:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
list(Event.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]) + list(Event.objects.filter(is_home=True))
```

Unfortunately, you cannot (as far as I can tell) combine queries *after* taking a slice, so conversion to lists is necessary.

If you *really really* want to have a `QuerySet` you can do:

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(id__in=Event.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5].values_list('id', flat=True)) | Q(is_home=True))
```

Which is extremely ugly.

Answer (score 2):

```
context['event_list'] = Event.objects.filter(is_home=True).order_by(-id)[:5]
```

Comment: I thought that he wanted last five items _and_ all items such that `is_home=True`.

Comment: @Siegmeyer +1 yes

Comment: @Siegmeyer when I read his  question again it seems like you are right